# HAProxy "tcp-request connection reject" not functioning as expected

Tags: haproxy

I have tried to implement a system to block ips if they are acting maliciously. It appeared to be working in testing but I am having some mixed results in my live environment.

What I have tried to do is block connections if they have an error rate > 10, an error count > 50 or a request rate > 150.

Firstly my frontend proxy has the configuration:

```
stick-table type ip size 100k expire 30s store http_err_rate(10000),http_err_cnt,http_req_rate(10000)
tcp-request connection track-sc0 src
tcp-request connection accept if { src -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.lst }
tcp-request connection reject if { sc0_http_err_rate gt 10 }
tcp-request connection reject if { sc0_http_err_cnt gt 50 }
tcp-request connection reject if { sc0_http_req_rate gt 150 }
```

I recently had an ip doing a scan which was not being blocked by haproxy, before blocking by ip-tables I checked the stats on the IP which showed:

```
echo "show table clientsecure key x.x.x.x" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.stat
# table: clientsecure, type: ip, size:102400, used:23
xx: key=x.x.x.x use=8 exp=0 http_req_rate(10000)=144 http_err_cnt=34235 http_err_rate(10000)=150
```

I feel like I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the haproxy configuration.

Am I using the stick-table correctly with the following tcp-request connection rules?

Does the "tcp-request connection reject" block incoming connections if one rule matches, or do they all need to match?

**Edit:**

Upon further testing I figured out the rules are only checked on new connections. So using "option httpclose" will stop people as soon as they hit the limits. Obviously not ideal for speed reasons, so going to experiment with keep-alive timeouts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I was only tracking on the connection on the front end any connections kept alive would still be able to run requests. So the solution is:

**Frontend:**

- create sticky table just with a gpc
- track the **connection** src using sc1
- create acl "is-abuser" if the gpc > 0
- reject connection if "is-abuser"

**Backends:**

- start sticky table with error rate, error count, request rate
- track the **content** src using sc2
- create abuse acls for the error rates, counts, request rate
- create acl to increase the gpc tracked from the frontend stick-table using sc1_inc_gpc
- reject content if abuse acls match and run then run increase gpc acl

Similar example I found directly from the manual (using sc0 and sc1 in place of sc1, sc2 in above explanation):

```
#Track per-frontend and per-backend counters, block abusers at the frontend when the backend detects abuse(and marks gpc0).
frontend http
    # Use General Purpose Couter 0 in SC0 as a global abuse counter
    # protecting all our sites
    stick-table type ip size 1m expire 5m store gpc0
    tcp-request connection track-sc0 src
    tcp-request connection reject if { sc0_get_gpc0 gt 0 }
    ...
    use_backend http_dynamic if { path_end .php }

backend http_dynamic
    # if a source makes too fast requests to this dynamic site (tracked
    # by SC1), block it globally in the frontend.
    stick-table type ip size 1m expire 5m store http_req_rate(10s)
    acl click_too_fast sc1_http_req_rate gt 10
    acl mark_as_abuser sc0_inc_gpc0(http) gt 0
    tcp-request content track-sc1 src
    tcp-request content reject if click_too_fast mark_as_abuser
```